# Present Continuous or Present Simple?

Tags: grammar, present-progressive, present-tense

Could you tell me if the sentence below is grammatically correct?

We usually **grow** vegetables in our garden, but this year we **are not growing** any.

I'm not completely sure that in the second part of the sentence I should use Present Continuous. If it's wrong to use this tense here, could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present continuous is correct.

If you say "this year we're not growing any," and e. g. it's still winter, present continuous means **a plan for the near future**. It is basically equivalent to saying "we will not grow any this year, we don't intend to, we are not going to."

If you say the phrase in the summer, you still need present continuous, but it'll mean **an action happening at or around the moment of speaking**.